# Sorting arrays manually in php without using sort()

Tags: php, sorting

Help. I already stucked in a logic and procedures in printing a sorted array lists without using sort().

```
<?php
$item = array(2, 1, 3);
$item_length = count($item);
for ($counter = 0; $counter < $item_length; $counter++) {
  if ($item[$counter] <= $item[$counter + 1]) {
   print $item[$counter];

   // now what I should do??

   }

 }
?>
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

Comment: It would be wiser to sort it first, and then print it, otherwise you will have to do many many loops...

Comment: yep i already did that using sort(), but the school instructed us not to use sort().

I stucked in invalid results... :-(

Comment: You need a nested loop to sort this array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the solution using bubble sort

```
<?php
$item = array(2, 1, 4,3,5,6);
$item_length = count($item);
for ($counter = 0; $counter < $item_length-1; $counter++) {
  for ($counter1 = 0; $counter1 < $item_length-1; $counter1++) {
    if ($item[$counter1] > $item[$counter1 + 1]) {
       $temp=$item[$counter1];
       $item[$counter1]=$item[$counter1+1];
       $item[$counter1+1]=$temp;
       }
    }
 }

//you can print the array using loop
print_r($item);
?>
```

Comment: thank you thank you a lot.. i just lost in logic... i already read about bubble sort but I din't get it thru it's technical jargons..

I will just use it as logic basis...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $item = array(2, 1, 3);
    $item_length = count($item);
    for ($counter = 0; $counter < $item_length; $counter++) {
        for ($t = $counter+1; $t < $item_length; $t++) {
            if ($item[$counter] < $item[$t]) {
                swapItem($counter,$t); // your function to swap two item with index
            }                                                                            
        }
    }
?>
```

basic sort function will be like this

Comment: thanks Tory.. I already figured it out 15 mins ago :-)  but your approach is different.  swapItem() didn't fall in my mind about that

Comment: I means like : SwapItem ($index1, $index2) { $temp=$item[$index1];
       $item[$index1]=$item[$index2];
       $item[$index2]=$temp; } || If you lost logic, I can help you. Contact me anytime if you want.